# Find Date in Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I'm trying to use a list of dates to find the same date in a data frame and using ifelse loop to add a new column. Here is the code:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- tibble(DateCol = seq(ymd("2021-01-01"),ymd("2021-05-31"),"days"))

df2 <- c("2021-02-04","2021-02-07","2021-02-17","2021-02-25")

for (i in 1:length(df$DateCol)) {
  if (df$DateCol[i] == df2) {
    df$ValueCol[i] <- "1"
    } else {
      df$ValueCol[i] <- "0"
      return(i)
    }
  }
```

The final df I get only has the first date of df2 is 1 in df$ValueCol. Not sure how to make this loop work, seems like there are some mistakes in the df$DateCol[i] == df2 part.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop.

```
df$ValueCol <- as.integer(df$DateCol %in% as.Date(df2))
df
```

`as.integer` is faster way than using `ifelse` with 1 and 0 as output.

```
df$ValueCol <- ifelse(df$DateCol %in% as.Date(df2), 1, 0)
```

---

Your loop can be corrected by using `%in%` instead of `==`, as we use `%in%` to compare more than 1 value.

```
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(DateCol = seq(ymd("2021-01-01"),ymd("2021-05-31"),"days"))

df2 <- as.Date(c("2021-02-04","2021-02-07","2021-02-17","2021-02-25"))
df$ValueCol <- NA
for (i in 1:length(df$DateCol)) {
  if (df$DateCol[i] %in% df2) {
    df$ValueCol[i] <- 1
  } else {
    df$ValueCol[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df <- tibble(DateCol = seq(ymd("2021-01-01"),ymd("2021-05-31"),"days"))

df2 <- ymd("2021-02-04","2021-02-07","2021-02-17","2021-02-25")
df3 <- df %>% mutate(ValueCol = if_else(DateCol %in% df2, 1, 0))
```